# Trying to animate a jump in canvas / JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm just trying to animate a jump in canvas, but I don't think I got the math formula properly, instead of doing a sine wave kind of motion, it just instantly telports, with no animation, any help would be great thanks.

```
var ctx = new CtxScene(500, 500, '1px solid black').create()
  , player = {
    x: 0,
        y: 0,
        moving: false,
        dir: undefined
  };



var i = 0;
(function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {  
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        checkDir();
        update();
    }, 1000 / 60);
})();

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 37) {
        player.moving = true;
        player.dir = 'left';
    } 
    if (e.which === 39) {
        player.moving = true;
        player.dir = 'right';
    }
    if (e.which === 38) {
        player.moving = true;
        player.dir = 'up';
    }
    if (e.which === 40) {
        player.moving = true;
        player.dir = 'down';
    }
    if (e.which === 32) {
        player.moving = true;
        player.dir = 'jump';
    }
   console.log(e.which);    
}

document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    player.moving = false;
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00A';
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 100, 100)
}

function checkDir() {

    if (player.moving) {

        if (player.dir === 'left') {
            player.x  -=5;
        } else if (player.dir === 'right') {
            player.x += 5;
        } else if (player.dir === 'up') {
            player.y -= 5;
        } else if (player.dir === 'down') {
            player.y += 5;
        } else if (player.dir === 'jump') {
            player.y = 100 * Math.sin(5*Math.PI/200);
        }
    }

}
```

the math is a few lines from the bottom (I'm almost 100% sure it's wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the easiest way to do this is to use physics, really really basic physics. Give your character a gravity force and at least a velocity in the Y direction, similar to this:

```
player.gravity= 0.92;

var characterUpdate= function(){
    player.y+=player.velocityY;
    player.velocityY+=player.gravity;
}
```

This will cause the player to constantly want to go downward (gravity) and you increase the velocityY to counter act this during a jump. You'll want to set some bounds to avoid the character going off the screen for now, something like:

```
if (player.y+player.height >= ctx.height) {
    player.y=ctx.height-player.height;
}
```

The added benefit of this method is that it takes care of any falls you might plan on including later.